# trying to understand scipy's optimize.minimize function, getting indexerror

Tags: scipy, ipython, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to write code that will optimize a multivariate function using sklearn's optimize function, but it keeps returning an IndexError, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

The code is this:

```
revcoeff = coefficients[::-1]
xdot = np.zeros(0)
normfeat1 = normfeat1.reshape(-1,1)
xdot = np.append(normfeat1, normfeat2.reshape(-1,1), axis=1)
a = revcoeff[1:3]
b = xdot[0, :]    

seed = np.zeros(5)   #does seed need to be the coefficients? not sure
fun = lambda x: np.multiply((1/666), np.power(np.sum(np.dot(a, xdot[x, :])-medianv[x]),2))     #costfunction

optsol = optimize.minimize(fun, seed)
```

where there are two features I'm using in my nearest neighbors algorithm. Coefficients for the fitted regression model are given into the array "coefficients".

What I'm having trouble understanding is 1) why my code is throwing a "IndexError: arrays used as indicies must be of integer or boolean type"....and also partially I'm confused by the optimize.minimize function itself. It takes in two input values, the function and x0 (an ndarray with initial guesses). What should x0 be, the coefficients values? Or do I pick random values, and how many are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

`np.zeros()` does not return integers by default. Try, for example, `np.zeros(5, dtype=int)` instead. It won't solve all of the problems with your code, though. You'll see some other error message.

Also, notice, that `1/666` returns 0 instead of 0.00150150. You probably want 1/666.0.

It would be helpful if you could clean up your code as half of it is of no use.

Comment: you're right, it does give an error, this time a "ValueError: objects not aligned" - does that have something to do with the length of values in my function or the seed array?

Comment: I guess that the length of `a` variable doesn't match `xdot[x, :]` variable, and the error comes from `np.dot()` but that's just a guess given that your code does not make it possible to replicate what you're seeing. It would be helpful if you could present a code that can be executed.